# Prevent insert on Client from Server's `allow`

Tags: node.js, meteor

I have `isServer` code:

```
coll.allow({ insert: isAllowed });
```

On the client, you can perform an insert.  There is a template that uses something like:

```
Template.foo.coll = function () { return coll.find({}); };
```

This displays all of the `coll` documents in the template as intended.

---

However, if `isAllowed` returns `false`, the client will still insert the new document in its own collection (seemingly) even though the server does not.

What this means is that if you insert a new item, it will appear on the client until you refresh (because it won't be loaded from the server since it was not inserted there).

How can I prevent the insert from occurring on the *client* as well as the server?  Is it safe to move `coll.allow` to `isClient` instead of `isServer`, or do I need it for both?

Comment: If the server doesn't allow the insertion, the client will remove its temporary inserted document.

Comment: @PeppeL-G it seems that it does not though.  I need to refresh the page before the invalid documents are not displayed on the client.  The callback for `.insert` *does* have the error argument.

Comment: If you on the client run `coll.find().fetch()` in the console (in the browser) after the insertion, the inserted document doesn't show up, does it?

Comment: @PeppeL-G I see that using `.fetch` makes it work.  The problem with this now is that there seems to be a flicker when an insert is attempted (either successfully or unsuccessfully).  Is there any way to get around this without having to reevaluate everything using `fetch`?

Comment: In a template helper it shouldn't matter if you return the cursor from `find()` or the array from `fetch()`; the template should be re-evaluated either case. The flicker is a result of one of Meteors seven principles, Latency Compensation, so you've probably solved it the right way (the Meteor way). However, in the new template engine (coming soon, I hope), there will hopefully be less flicker due to a new (better) rendering model.

Comment: @ExplosionPills this is called latency compensation in meteor world and indeed is the intended behaviour. normally, a user would not insert from the console and you'd set up an insert flow that would only be rejected per constraints while you optimistically assume the insertion would go through. This way, the user feels the app to appear more responsive and snappy.

Comment: @SerkanDurusoy wonderful, but how do I get it to stop what appears to be an insert on the client?

Comment: You can do server side inserts using calls to your custom meteor methods that do the insert. But you'll then lose latency compensation.

Comment: @ExplosionPills The best solution is to make sure that you never inserts documents on the client that the server will refuse (the allow/deny restrictions should only be there to prevent bad guys from doing unintended things).

Comment: @PeppeL-G this still results in duplicate validation on the client and server; how can I obviate this?

Comment: @ExplosionPills Not necessary. Define a global function responsible for doing the validation that's accessible on both the server and the client. In the allow function, make a call to this function. Before you insert document on the client, make a call to this function.

Comment: @PeppeL-G this still results in duplicated functionality (although the code itself is not duplicated).  I guess that's good enough.

Comment: @ExplosionPills Aha, with "duplicated functionality" you mean that the validation is done on both the client and the server? Sorry, I didn't get that. But I would see that as something positive: when the users fills in a form wrong, the user will be notified about it immediately without the "communication with the server"-delay, and the server won't spend precious resources on validating data users filled in wrong.